# GWT - resistance of JavaScript debugger

Tags: java, javascript, security, gwt

I want ask you about GWT security. Because GWT code is converted to JavaScript code, can a user change the value of my variable using a JavaScript debugger?

For example: I have a timer, it counts from 10:00 to 0:00. Can the user change this value through a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**GWT security cannot be decided on the OBF and whether user can edit the js.** Take a look at the below Obfuscated GWT JS output. I do not believe it is unsafe and can you find whether i am using counter, timer, etc.

[image]

GWT security is as better than any most javascript frameworks out there. And GWT has guidelines to handle other non-amateur security threats -

### Reference - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/security_for_gwt_applications

Comment: I reviewed the java debugger in my app and i saw something like on your image and I wonder how someone can find there something ? I think it's impossible... But I'm not experienced programmer.

Comment: Go through the GWT security reference. Focus on XSRF , XSS and SafeHTML security threats. You are pretty safe on the editing js side as long as you clean up your XSS , XSRF and SafeHTML usage :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes they can, GWT makes it harder by [obfuscating](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/1.6/FAQ_DebuggingAndCompiling#Why_is_my_GWT-generated_JavaScript_gibberish?) the output but even then the debugger in the browser will try to [format the code](http://cristian-radulescu.ro/article/pretty-print-javascript-with-google-chrome.html) to make it readable.

Comment: You are listing GWT pretty mode feature as security threat. It is not meant to be used for Production mode. GWT PRETTY mode and DETAILED mode js compilation are for development teams to handle hard to debug browser only bugs....

Comment: Where do I say that GWT pretty mode is a security threat?

Comment: "Debugger in the browser will try to format the code" will most often be interpreted as browser utility feature rather than gwt compiler feature :)

Comment: It will hopefully be interpreted that way because that's what I meant - you didn't answer my question.

Comment: That's what the "format the code" link is about - it won't be able to put human readable identifiers in there but will split it into multiple lines based on the structure which eases stepwise debugging. As I said GWT's obfuscation makes it hard - but if someone with skill and sufficient motivation can do this sort of thing.

Comment: Ah... now i understand . You mean to state small pieces of code can be analyzed by a determined "hacker" by keeping random js break points and exercising the application. It would be more plausible if the application is small or if the gwt splits it to "deferred" .js files. A trade off i guess to be on web and away from flash/applet!!!